# Add text in custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy on my WordPress website (for WooCommerce products).

There is an editor on the edit page of this taxonomy. The data entered into this editor is displayed at the top of the taxonomy page (above the products). While I want it to be displayed at the bottom of the page (below the products and above the footer).

My WordPress theme is Flatsome.

I don't have much programming knowledge. please direct me. Thankful